# How can I tell evil which language mode to use for indentation?

Tags: evil

`evil-indent` does not work in `ein`, it simply collapses all indentations of the selected region. Can I somehow tell Evil that it is dealing with Python code?

Comment: There's a [ticket for this](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/103).